# Getting error "void can't be pass"

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

void  message() ;
int main()
{
   message ( message ());
    return 0;
}
void message()
{
    printf("it is small");
}
```

I am getting a compilation error `"void can't be pass"`.  What does it mean and how can I fix it?

Comment: What are you trying to do? `message(message());` makes no sense.

Comment: I seriously doubt that you're getting "void can't be pass" as an error message. Please copy-and-paste the *exact* message. And for future reference, you need to format your code properly; you don't need nearly so many blank lines, and you need to use the `{}` button (or indent by 4 spaces) so it's shown as code.

Comment: GCC gives `error: invalid use of void expression` for the line `message ( message ());`.  What does your compiler really say?

Answer (score 2):

The line `message ( message ());` calls `message()` and then passes its return value to another call to `message()`. This will not work, since, as the error message states, you can't pass a `void` result to another function (since it isn't actually a result at all). Stop what you are doing, and think about what you actually want the code to do.

Comment: It's also worth mentioning that in C, you must declare it `message(void)` if it is to be a method that accepts no arguments. `message()` declares _a_ function with an unspecified amount of arguments.

Answer (score 0):

`message` doesn't return a value. You can't use it in an expression like:

```
message ( message ());
```

Answer (score 0):

The line    `message ( message ())`   is wrong. Because you defined the    `message()`   as a void function, so you can`t pass any parameters to message().` And for a void function you should ended it by line of return. So I think you program should be :

```
#include<stdio.h>
    void  message() ;
    int main()
    {
        message ();
        return 0;
    }
    void message()
    {
        printf("it is small");
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

In addition, you define the function "void message()" cannot accept any parameter.

Comment: Not so; an empty parameter list means it can take anything because they're unspecified. It only means no parameters at all in C++. To declare a function that cannot accept parameters in C, one needs to use `void` as the parameter list.

Comment: @Leushenko: True, but since it's *defined* with no parameters, calling it with one or more arguments has undefined behavior. Which is why old-style declarations and definition are obsolescent. Always use prototypes.